# How to run shell script on multiple EC2 instances using AWS CLI?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to do a simple AWS CLI command that can run a shell command to multiple instances.

I know first I need to get the list of instances ids:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=tag:Group,Values=Development" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId]' --output text
```

I then will have to assign them to an array. Then loop through each instance id and send the command.

Do we have an option for aws to send a shell command to an instance with a specific id?

Something like this:

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --document-name "shellscript"
```

I keep getting this error:

> An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation:

I've made sure that the SSM agent is running on that specific instance and made sure everything is correct according to [these docs pages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_SendCommand.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034797/invalidinstanceid-an-error-occurred-invalidinstanceid-when-calling-the-sendco)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ssm send-command`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html).

A sample command to see ip address of instance:

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "your id's" --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --comment "IP config" --parameters "commands=ifconfig" --output text
```

Modify command as per your needs.

---

In case you've got the error, this can happen when you don't have SSM setup on the instance you're trying to access. For a list of instances where you can run SSM commands, run:

```
aws ssm describe-instance-information --output text
```

<sup>See: [InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47034797).</sup>

Comment: I've tried that command and I kept getting this error: 
"An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation"

Comment: What Error , please post or if it's bigger edit question accordingly

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: You have to pass the instance ids as separate string values --instance-ids <id> <id> <id> etc.., not --instance-ids "<id> <id> <id>". Quoting the list of ids as shown here will pass them all as one string.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a script with Python using Boto3.

```html
import boto3
import botocore
import paramiko

tagkey = 'Environment'
tagvalue = 'DEV'

# list_instances functions returns a list of ip addresses containing a set of tags
def list_instances(tagkey, tagvalue):

    ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')

    response = ec2client.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'tag:'+tagkey,
                'Values': [tagvalue]
            }
       ]
    )
    instancelist = []
    for reservation in (response["Reservations"]):
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
            instancelist.append(instance["PublicDnsName"])
    return instancelist

# Results of the function get stored in a list.
list = list_instances(tagkey, tagvalue)

key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/home/ec2-user/key.pem")
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Looping through all the instannces in the list
for instance_ip in list[:]:
                # Connect/ssh to an instance
    try:
                # Here 'ec2-user' is user name and 'instance_ip' is public IP of EC2
                client.connect(hostname=instance_ip, username="ec2-user", pkey=key)

                # Execute a command after connecting/ssh to an instance
                stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("touch test")

                # close the client connection once the job is done
                print "Command sent:",instance_ip

    except Exception, e:
        print e
```