# Travis docker build to AWS ec2 docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, travis-ci

I am developing a micro-service architecture based application using Spring-boot and Angular7 for the front end. What I need to do is to deploy it to a docker I have installed on my AWS ec2 instance using Travis.

What I have done so far is created a travis.yml file

```
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk8
services:
  - mysql
  - rabbitmq
  - redis-server

before_install:
  - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb;'

image: my-service/aws-cli-docker

variables:
   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "##########"
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "##########"

deploy_stage:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids "i-########" --parameters '{"commands":["sudo docker-compose -f /home/ubuntu/docker-compose.yml up -d --no-deps --build"],"executionTimeout":["3600"]}' --timeout-seconds 600 --region us-east-2
```

My dockerfile is in the source of the sevice as is as follows:

```
FROM java:8 
VOLUME /tmp
ADD ./target/myService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  my-service.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m  -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing  -jar  /my-service.jar" ]
```

nd my docker compose file is in the home/ubuntu path on my ec2 instance as follows:

```
services:
    vehicle-service:
    image: my-service/aws-cli-docker
    ports:
        -8081:8081
```

I my Travis build works and tests run but there's no deployment or any errors about the docker image. Can someone figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: In the Travis log's does it have a return code?

Comment: yes, the tests are passed and returns 0

Comment: Just want to double check, is the instance (--instance-ids "i-########") in the same region 'us-east-2'?

Comment: yeah it is.. it says availability zone - us-east-2a so i guess that's right

Comment: Yep, sounds right. So the tests pass, the instance is available in the target region. Do you see any output after the tests? Possibly one of the other processes in "deploy_stage:"?

Comment: No nothing after the tests.. Looks like it something wrong in the travis.yml I just started using travis yesterday so I cant figure it out

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I was under the impress Travis was starting. Are you able to manually trigger an execution from the Travis web console?

Comment: Im very new to travis. Let me try that too. Do you think my script is right?

Comment: The yml looks correct; If the test complete but the travis process does not start, I do not believe the issue is within Travis. Rather the process/trigger to start Travis.

Comment: I edited the yml and now i cant get a different error - An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation:  but my instance ID is correct and I also have the ssm client installed and running

Comment: Ah, excellent. That error has a definitive resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034797/invalidinstanceid-an-error-occurred-invalidinstanceid-when-calling-the-sendco