# An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation

Tags: python, boto3

The below is the code which i'm running from python to execute commands in aws ec2 instance

```
import time
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # boto3 client
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
    
    # getting instance information
    describeInstance = client.describe_instances()

    InstanceId=['i-01312fe89cc73adfe']
    # fetchin instance id of the running instances
    for i in describeInstance['Reservations']:
        for instance in i['Instances']:
            if instance["State"]["Name"] == "running":
                InstanceId.append(instance['InstanceId'])

    # looping through instance ids
    for instanceid in InstanceId:
        # command to be executed on instance
        response = ssm.send_command(
                InstanceIds=[instanceid],
                DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
                Parameters={'commands': ['ls']} 
                )

        # fetching command id for the output
        command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
        
        time.sleep(3)
        
        # fetching command output
        output = ssm.get_command_invocation(
              CommandId=command_id,
              InstanceId=instanceid
            )
        print(output)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Thanks from Srce Cde!')
    }
```

he following scenarios are checked :

- Instance id is valid: yes (get from aws ssm describe-instance-information --output text)
- Instance is in a same region: yes
- Instance is not currently in the Running state : yes
- Instance have the AWS SSM agent installed and running : yes

In additional, when I check instance information, it gives the correct instance ID which I put in my lambda function

```
aws ssm describe-instance-information --output text

INSTANCEINFORMATIONLIST 3.0.529.0       ip-192-168-0-4.eu-west-3.compute.internal       192.168.0.4     i-01312fe89cc73adfe     False   2021-07-11T06:08:14.892000+02:00        Online  Amazon Linux    Linux   2       EC2Instance
```

**Resonse:**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation: ",
  "errorType": "InvalidInstanceId",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda.py\", line 30, in lambda_handler\n    Parameters={'commands': ['ls']}\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 357, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 676, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `describe_instances` if you are hard-coding the id? What does `describe_instances` return? Does it have your instance?

Comment: Hello, hardcode instance id is only for debug purpose. I'm using `InstanceId=[]` but still giving same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034797/invalidinstanceid-an-error-occurred-invalidinstanceid-when-calling-the-sendco)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checking the status of "Instance Status" if it is "ok"?

It's different from just checking the instance's "Running" state.. it could be that